# Adding a limit in NDSolve to avoid division by zero

Tags: differential-equations, singularity

I'm trying to solve a set of differential equations in which one of the functions that describe the time derivative gets values which make it divide by zero

```
x'[t] = (Exp[x] - 1)/(Exp[x] - 1 + x)
```

So what happens is that when `NDSolve` gets values of `x=0` you get that an `Infinite expression of 1/0 encountered`.

However, when I have `x=0` I would actually like to replace it with the limit of `x->0`

```
 Limit[(Exp[x] - 1)/(Exp[x] - 1 + x), x -> 0]
```

which is `1/2`.

Any suggestions of how to implement the idea in `NDSolve`?

**Addition**

Look for simplicity at the following case

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == (Exp[x[t]] - 1)/(Exp[x[t]] - 1 + x[t]), 
  x[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Here `x'[t]` encounters `1/0` in the initial condition, but I would like it to get the limit of `x->0` which is `1/2`. 
Note that in my problem which is far more complicated, `x'[t]` encounters this limit many times and the value of the limit is varied with respect to other state variables, therefore I would like the limit to be calculated in each iteration.

Comment: Does your real problem involve `1/0` in the initial conditions or elsewhere?  I find that your simple example runs fine as long as you don't use `x[0] == 0`.

Comment: @ChrisK, elsewhere, actually all along the solution periodically. I gave the initial condition as an example.

Comment: Could you give an example where it doesn't work `x[0] != 0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`If`:

```
eq = With[{x = x[t]}, D[x, t] == If[x == 0, 1/2, (Exp[x] - 1)/(Exp[x] - 1 + x)]]

sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, x[0] == -1}, x, {t, 0, 6}]

Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, 6}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

## Update

If the limit needs to be calculated each time it encounters zero:

```
eq = With[{x = x[t]}, 
  With[{expr = (Exp[x] - 1)/(Exp[x] - 1 + x)}, 
   D[x, t] == If[x == 0, Limit[expr, x -> 0], expr]]]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, please look at my addition to the question. It is important that the limit will be calculated each time it encounters zero.

Comment: Please also keep the answer restricted to 'NDSolve' if possible.

Comment: @jarhead Check my update.